# Zend Translate - Set Locale per User

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

I'm developing a multi-lingual site.

I've put a Zend_Translate object in the Zend_Registry and I use it to translate all static texts to the selected locale.

My question is how do I change the locale when the user chooses another language?

If I get the translate object from the registry, call setLocale , and put it again in the registry , will it hold only for that user or for the whole application?

Thanks.

Comment: I found out that using a controller plugin to set the locale of the zend translate in the registry works... is that the only way?

Comment: Probably not *the* only one, but if you would like to set it based on an URL parametre, then I would say it's at least the most convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a plugin for that.

In short: create your plugin and add the `routeStartup()` and `routeShutdown()` methods to it. In the former one, set the locale string in a request param and, if needed, also set the requesr URI to contain the locale string. Correct locale string detection is up to you - you can either use a cookie, URL parametre, browser's accepted language header or any combination of the three. In the latter one, create your `Zend_Translate` object based on the locale you have set earlier.

Here is [how it looks like in my CMS](https://bitbucket.org/mingos/ucms/src/a2d228751663/application/plugins/MultiLanguage.php).

Here is a [tutorial regarding the use of the language parametre in the URL](http://www.m4d3l-network.com/developpement/php/zend-framework/add-language-route-to-your-zend-framework-project/). You may also check [how I do it in my CMS](https://bitbucket.org/mingos/ucms/src/a2d228751663/application/Bootstrap.php) (see the _initRouter method).

I hope this info is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Poedit for this purpose ..go thru this link for more

```
techie.ayyappadas.com/how-do-use-poeditor
```

Comment: I have a translation file.. I need a php (zend) code to give the user an option to change the selected language.